# Dart StreamController: Test timed out after 30 seconds

Tags: flutter, dart, testing, stream

I'm trying to create a reactive `SharedPreferences` utility but I'm stuck with this issue.
This is my class

```
class SPUtil {
    final _workoutsStreamController = StreamController<
          Result<Iterable<PreferencesWorkout>, Exception>>.broadcast();

    @override
    Stream<Result<Iterable<PreferencesWorkout>, Exception>> getWorkouts() async* {
      final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      _workoutsStreamController.sink.add(success(_getStoredWorkouts(prefs)));
      yield* _workoutsStreamController.stream;
    }
}
```

And this is my test

```
test("getWorkouts SHOULD return empty list WHEN nothing is stored",
        () async {
      SharedPreferences.setMockInitialValues({});

      final actual = await _sut.getWorkouts().first;

      expect((actual as Success).value, []);
    });
```

Whenever I run this test it loops for 30 seconds and it returns this error

```
dart:async  _startMicrotaskLoop

TimeoutException after 0:00:30.000000: Test timed out after 30 seconds. See https://pub.dev/packages/test#timeouts
```

Everything works fine if I use this implementation instead

```
class SPUtil {
    @override
    Stream<Result<Iterable<PreferencesWorkout>, Exception>> getWorkouts() async* {
      final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      yield success(_getStoredWorkouts(prefs));
    }
}
```

So I assume my test is correct.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I finally found the issue, `StreamController` doesn't emit anything if is not listened, hence the test goes in timeout.

```
test("getWorkouts SHOULD return empty list WHEN nothing is stored",
        () async {
      SharedPreferences.setMockInitialValues({});

      final actual = _sut.getWorkouts().first;      
      actual.listen((event) {});

      final actualResult = await actual;
      expect((actualResult as Success).value, []);
    });
```

Comment: Very nice to come back 3 days later with the answer !